# Как в NavigationView в header установить текст?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

У меня есть вот такой `NavigationView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_mainsecond"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_mainsecond"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_therd_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

и вот такой `header`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tvName"
    android:src="@drawable/newlogo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textEmail"
    android:text="Current user name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textEmail"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Мне нужно в этот `header` в поле для имени `user` поставить его имя, а в поле для `email` поставить соответственно `email`

Я понимаю, что все стандартно и нужно найти по `id view` с которым хочешь работать и установить в него `TextView`.

Но когда я нахожу `view` и ставлю `text`, то вылетает ошибка, что такого `view` еще нет. Это логично т.к. `NavigationView` еще не открыт...

Так вот вопрос. Как отследить что `NavigationView` уже открыт и только после этого устанавливать `text` в `view`?

Если я в `onCreate()` нахожу и устанавливаю текст

```
TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView textEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textEmail);

    tvName.setText("test");
    textEmail.setText("test");
```

то получаю такую ошибку в строке `tvName.setText("test");`

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.android.camera2basic, PID: 32152
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.camera2basic/com.example.android.camera2basic.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Если применять такой подход, то ошибки нет, но текст остается таким как по умолчанию

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    RelativeLayout headerView = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_mainsecond, null);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView textEmail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
    tvName.setText("name");
    textEmail.setText("email");
```

Comment: Вы эти данные из базы же берете? если да, то есть ли у вас проверка(фнкция) что юзер залогинился?

Comment: Желательно бы текст ошибки и код где падает

Comment: @iFr0z данные беру из `SharedPref` , ну как проверка... Я проверяю, если там данные лежат значит из нужно установить

Comment: @АндроидАндроид добавил

Comment: Ну, ошибка из-за того что вы пытаетесь выдернуть вьюшки из второй разметки, а установлена у вас xml-ka то первая=)

Comment: @АндроидАндроид вы имеете ввиду, что сам хедер это отдельная xml-ka? Значит, нужно попробовать ее заинфлейтить и на инфлейте найти нужные мне вью?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста как вы в классе указываете на header в navigationview

Comment: @iFr0z никак)) наверное вот это и проблема) А как на него указать заинфлейтить и на инфлейте найти нужные мне вью?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Угу, как то так. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30660069/4829111

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko ошибки нет больше?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. Получить NavigationView

`NavigationView nv = ...;`

2. Получить разметку его Header

`View header = nv.getHeaderView(0);`

3. Найти нужные поля и с ними что-то сделать

`TextView tv = (TextView)header.findViewById(...);`

Comment: Точно!!)) Круто)) От куда вы это знаете? Все заработало! Спасибо!

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну... Когда-то делал так... А память не очень плоха, вот и всё)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko как правило все давно известно и [аккуратно записано](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) - нужно только прочитать и выбрать нужное :)