# Navigation Drawer header

Tags: java, android, view, android-navigation-drawer

В андроид студии есть шаблон для создания Navigation Drawer. Мне надо изменить его заголовок программно. У меня приложение при использовании методов:

```
twNavBarName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_tw_name);
twNavBarEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_tw_email);
twNavBarName.setText("fdfs");
```

падает и не выводит в лог вообще ничего. Как изменить заголовки с именем и емейлом, на рисунке они показаны под номером 1 и 2.
[image: Navigation Drawer]

Comment: Если найдете решения, выложите сюда пожалуйста. Тоже интересно))

Comment: [Решилось все данным способом!!!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528889/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-navigationview-%D0%B2-header-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82)

Comment: @ЕвгенийДементьев, если ответ мой вам помог, то вы можете проголосовать за него в том вопросе)