# Получить ID ресурса из другого layout

Tags: java, android, ресурсы

В общем есть два layout-файла для Navigation Drawer. Как из второго я могу получить ID ресурса avatar, если в классе стоит setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation)?

**activity_navigation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:openDrawer="start" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/nav_drawer_design"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_drawer_header**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_header_nav_drawer"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar_man_1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickUserAvatar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="youremail@main.ru"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Спасибо большое за любую помощь!

Comment: Может вам это поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528914/17609? Вообще вопрос не очень понятен(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующий код позволил мне получить ID ресурса изображения:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
ImageView avatar = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_header_useravatar);
```

Answer (score 1):

ID ресурса avatar - `R.id.avatar`.