# Как поменять headerLayout в NavigationView программно

Tags: android, android-navigation-view

Делаю приложение, которым можно пользоваться как авторизованным, так и не авторизованным пользователям. Есть боковое меню. Хочу чтобы для авторизованных/не авторизованных пользователей выводилось разное меню. Как лучше это сделать?

Есть идея проверять выполнен ли вход в приложение или нет, и по итогу проверки менять headerLayout и menu NavigationView на нужное мне, но не могу понять как это сделать.

Так выглядит мой NavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Наверное вам вот это поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528914/17609

Comment: То есть Вы предлагаете редактировать текущие header и menu? Но можно ли как-то реализовать мой способ?

Comment: Я лишь показал как можно получить программно вьюху хедера. Вроде бы аналогично можно её и заменить. В доке есть методы `add/get/remove/inflate`. Вам по идее можно использовать `get->remove->add` для ваших целей.